# Counter too long subfigure

Tags: subfloats, counters

I'm trying to make a igure with more than 26 subfigures, therefore, the counter of the alphabet is not enough since it goes only to the z. I tried as suggested in other posts to use the package alphalph like this:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{graphics,graphicx,color} 
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{psfrag,epsfig}
\renewcommand{\thesubfigure}{\alphalph{subfigure}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]{figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_trck.eps}\label{fig:a_trck}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]{figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_segm.eps}\label{fig:a_segm}}
\subfigure[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]{figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_SOBS.eps}\label{fig:a_SOBS}}

%and so on until 32 subfigures

\caption{Segmentation performance}
\label{fig:pedestrians}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

However, I get this error for the other figures in the document (which are not with automatic enumeration): "Missing number treated as zero".

The other figures are declared as:

```
\begin{figure}[!h]
\centering
\subfigure[\scriptsize{distribution with heavy tails}]{\includegraphics[width=.48\columnwidth]{Figures/Theory/PDF1n}\label{fig:PDF1}}
 \subfigure[\scriptsize{distribution with light tails}]{\label{fig:PDF2}
 \includegraphics[width=.48\columnwidth]{Figures/Theory/PDF2n}}
\caption{\scriptsize{Kernel bandwidth selection strategy}}.
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail, preferably in the form of a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) so that we can see the packages you're using and some more context. It should start with `\documentclass` and end with `\end{document}`.

Comment: unrelated but don't use `[!h]` usually latex will warn about this and change it to `[!ht]` otherwise the figure would most likely go to end of document, but you ought really include `p` as well to give the figure a chance of being positioned.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\alphalph` needs a counter value as argument. However  package `subfigure` is obsolete, use `subfig` instead:

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}%  delete [demo] after testing
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]  {figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_trck.eps}\label{fig:a_trck}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]{figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_segm.eps}\label{fig:a_segm}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=0.23\columnwidth]{figures/Segmentation/Pedestrians_SOBS.eps}\label{fig:a_SOBS}}

\caption{Segmentation performance}
\label{fig:pedestrians}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are missing the `e` in obsolete :-)

Comment: well it was not excatly what you said, however I saw what I was doing wrong from your answer, there was missing the \value inside the \renewcomand... Thanks anyway