# Too many subfigures, counter too large in pylatex

Tags: subfloats, counters, pylatex

I am trying to create a figure that has more than 26 subfigures using `pylatex`. I understand from other posts such as [Counter too long subfigure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150428/counter-too-long-subfigure) that the way to fix this in a normal LaTeX editor would be to append the following to the preamble:

```latex
\usepackage{alphalph}
\renewcommand\thesubfigure{\alphalph{\value{subfigure}}
```

However, I am not sure how to implement such a fix in `pylatex` or is this the right way to go about it.

My code is currently as follows:

```py
from pylatex import Document, Section, Subsection, Figure, SubFigure, NoEscape, Command, Package
from pathlib import Path
if __name__ == '__main__':
    with doc.create(Section('Clustering results')):
        doc.append('These are all the images from the PPP-static run')
    # We need to iterate across the cluster_list 
    # Enumerate seems to be a convenient way of keeping count of iterations
        for cluster_number in cluster_list:
            # The first for loop goes through the total number of clusters e.g. 0-23
            # For each cluster number, define a figure
            with doc.create(Subsection('Cluster %s.' % cluster_number)):
                doc.append('These are the images in %s:' % cluster_number)

                with doc.create(Figure(position='htbp')) as fig:
                    for index, row in df_affinity.iterrows():
                        if cluster_number == row["Clustering Labels"]: 
                                print ("yay")
                                image_name= str(row["label"])
                                file_location = str("./pppstatic/PPP_Static_200_PX/")
                                image_location = file_location + image_name
                                img_path = Path(image_location)
                                with doc.create(SubFigure(position="htbp")) as pic:
                                    pic.add_image(image_location)
                                    pic.add_caption("%s." % image_name)
doc.generate_pdf(clean_tex=False)
```